# Telegram бот не отвечает на сообщения

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

*Telegram* бот не отвечает на сообщения, такая же проблема была на стадии выбора проблемы, но решилась через *call.data.*
Сейчас он не отвечает на сообщение с указанным текстом. Запускается без ошибок.

```
import telebot

from telebot import types, TeleBot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

sex = ''
name = ''


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    start = types.KeyboardButton('Начать')
    markup.add(start)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, я - бот помощник по тому-то тому...', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def sex(message):
    global sex
    if message.text == "Начать":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
        male = types.KeyboardButton('Мужской')
        female = types.KeyboardButton('Женский')
        markup.add(male, female)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Укажите ваш пол.", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_sex)


def get_sex(message):
    global sex
    sex = message.text
    if message.text == "Мужской":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Укажите своё имя", parse_mode='html')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name)
    elif message.text == "Женский":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Укажите своё имя", parse_mode='html')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Повторите попытку", parse_mode='html')


def get_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup();  # наша клавиатура
    key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='yes')  # кнопка «Да»
    keyboard.add(key_yes)  # добавляем кнопку в клавиатуру
    key_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='nosa')  # кнопка << Нет >>
    keyboard.add(key_no)
    question = f'Ваш пол - {sex}, а имя - {name}?'
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=question, reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
        prob1 = types.KeyboardButton('Problem 1')
        prob2 = types.KeyboardButton('Problem 2')
        prob3 = types.KeyboardButton('Problem 3')
        markup.add(prob1, prob2, prob3)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Отлично, укажите свою проблему:', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, get_problem)
    elif call.data == 'nosa':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
        male = types.KeyboardButton('Мужской')
        female = types.KeyboardButton('Женский')
        markup.add(male, female)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Укажите ваш пол.", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, get_sex)
    else:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Повторите попытку", parse_mode='html')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_problem(message):
    global problem
    problem = message.text
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    yes = types.KeyboardButton('Да')
    markup.add(yes)
    no = types.KeyboardButton('Нет')
    markup.add(no)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Ваша проблема - {problem}?', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def resend_answer(message):
    if message.text == 'Да':
        bot.send_message(bot.chat.id, "Хорошо, перeсылаю...", parse_mode='html')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```